# How to change colname of nested dataframe

Tags: r, tibble

Say we have a nested dataframe as below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

  df <- iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      nest()
  df

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    data             
  <fct>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

If I want to replace the first element of `colnames` of each dataframe with `new_name`, I tried:

```r
df_new <- iris %>%
          group_by(Species) %>%
          nest() %>%
          map(data, ~assign(colnames(.x)[[1]], "new_name"))

Error: Can't convert a `data.frame` object to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Why the code does not work as expected? What's the correct way to achieve this (I prefer a way using `pipe` and `map` methods rather than a `for` loop method)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be `rename_at` after looping through the `list` of data.frames with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>% 
            mutate(data = map(data, ~.x %>% 
                             rename_at(1, ~ "new_name")))
names(df_new$data[[1]])
#[1] "new_name"     "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```